# VBA to count distinct dates based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using this formula to calculate the unique number of dates for each user in column R

```
=SUM(IF(Q1=$J$2:$J$39115, 1/(COUNTIFS($J$2:$J$39115, Q1, $H$2:$H$39115, $H$2:$H$39115)), 0))
```

This formula works, but takes forever to calculate due to the large number of rows it has to work through.  I am sure there must be a quicker way using a macro or a vba.

Column J contains the list of users (users appears multiple times) and column H contains the dates.

I need to calculate the number of days worked by each user in column Q.(column Q contains the unique list of users .

Answer (score 0):

Add the following into a VBA module:

```
Public Function count_distinct(user As Range, userlist As Range, datelist As Range) As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, dates() As Variant, found As Boolean, this_date As Variant
    Dim varUL As Variant, varDL As Variant, unique_count As Long

    varUL = userlist.Value
    varDL = datelist.Value
    ReDim dates(0 To 0)

    For i = 1 To UBound(varUL, 1)
        If varUL(i, 1) = user Then
            found = False
            this_date = varDL(i, 1)
            For j = 1 To unique_count
                If this_date = dates(j) Then
                    found = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
            If Not found Then
                unique_count = unique_count + 1
                ReDim Preserve dates(0 To unique_count)
                dates(unique_count) = this_date
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    count_distinct = unique_count
End Function
```

Then replace your formula in column R with: `=count_distinct(Q1,$J$2:$J$39115,$H$2:$H$39115)`

It's not the quickest and I am sure it could be improved, but it may give you back a few minutes!!

Comment: Wow, wow, wow.  Thanks a million. Giving me back quite a few minutes.